# Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGRect

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts, react-native-chart-kit

Facing this issue, when I am using two libraries  react-native-d3multiline-chart for line chart and for the bar chart I am using react-native-svg-charts. Both the libraries are using same react-native-svg, when I am using react-native-svg, it is showing the above error. How can we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the library `npm-force-resolution`s, This modifies `package-lock.json` to force the installation of specific version of a transitive dependency (dependency of dependency), made the following changes to your `package.json`

```js
"resolutions": {
     "hoek": "4.2.1"
}

"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

remove and install node_modules

> rm -rf node_modules && npm install

hope this will work for you.